# Is every compound that has a H-bond donating group soluble in water?

Tags: solubility

I am wondering if there is any general rule of thumb

Comment: There are hardly any such simple generalisations that can be made in chemistry for the solubility of compounds. If the compound has a large nonpolar domain, clearly it won't be water soluble despite having an -OH group.

Comment: If we are making generalisations, I would say they are harmful. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Definitely not. 
For instance, palmitic acid with a pK$_\mathrm{a}$ of 4.75 has a water solubility of only 0.04 mg/L.

A general rule of thumb is that every oxygen can solubilize four carbon atoms but there are many exceptions. 
I addressed a similar question [here](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/97435/how-can-we-say-whether-or-not-an-organic-compound-is-soluble).

Nitrogen also makes the compound more soluble, but there it depends very much on the pH.